# divs overlapping each other

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #25274D;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-right: 1vw;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.4s;
  height: 100%;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #464866;
  color: #2E9CCA;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  line-height: 7vh;
}

#top__nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: darkblue;
  left: 0;
}

#top__nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1vw;
}

.Gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  position: relative;
}

.revealCard {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #25274D;
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #464866;
  perspective: 1000;
  margin: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.revealCard:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: #2E9CCA;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  color: #2E9CCA;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px auto;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dynamicText {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.appearOnScroll {
  color: #2E9CCA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#form {
  margin-top: 90px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.form__fields {
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #2E9CCA;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
}

.input:focus {
  background-color: #2E9CCA;
  color: #25274D;
}

.star {
  color: #2E9CCA;
}

.Fields {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top__nav">
  <div id="card">
    <ul id="top__nav__menu">
      <img id="logo" src="NewProject/Logo.png">
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Free Trial</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Samples</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Q-Bank</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=67fd942ed774f3de1db50cf3dd0065eb&w=1000&q=80">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <img class="img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TdpBRZ0dZhw/maxresdefault.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <p>Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=67fd942ed774f3de1db50cf3dd0065eb&w=1000&q=80">
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <p>Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcrkTylq_NcR1xOsclrGiDsbEPFpRFlLK_UxpB4zuF9O3Uvwu5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dynamicText">
  <p class="appearOnScroll">See the magic below!</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">Signup For Your Free Beta Trial Today!</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">This text appears on scroll</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">This text appears on scroll</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">This text appears on scroll</p>
</div>
<div id="form">
  <form action="">
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Full Name :<span class="star"> * </span></label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Address line 1:<span class="star"> * </span></label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="address_line_1" placeholder="Address line 1" required><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Address line 2:</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="address_line_2" placeholder="Address line 2"><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Address line 3:</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="address_line_3" placeholder="Address line 3"><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Email :<span class="star"> * </span></label>
      <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail" required><br/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The form is coming on top of the text in the div `#dynamicText`, I have tried many things like removing `position:absolute` from or clear:both from everywhere but I couldn't fix it. Please help. Also it would be nice if I have to change the css properties of form element only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The height: 30vh; in your #dynamicText is smaller then the content you have in it. Removing it or setting it to auto does fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height property in the `#dynamicText` seems to be giving trouble. Removing it takes out the overlap. Alternatively, using min-height instead works as well.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #25274D;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-right: 1vw;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.4s;
  height: 100%;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #464866;
  color: #2E9CCA;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  line-height: 7vh;
}

#top__nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: darkblue;
  left: 0;
}

#top__nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1vw;
}

.Gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  position: relative;
}

.revealCard {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #25274D;
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #464866;
  perspective: 1000;
  margin: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.revealCard:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: #2E9CCA;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  color: #2E9CCA;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px auto;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dynamicText {
  max-width: 100%;
  /*height: 30vh;*/
  font-size: 40px;
}

.appearOnScroll {
  color: #2E9CCA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#form {
  margin-top: 90px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.form__fields {
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #2E9CCA;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
}

.input:focus {
  background-color: #2E9CCA;
  color: #25274D;
}

.star {
  color: #2E9CCA;
}

.Fields {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top__nav">
  <div id="card">
    <ul id="top__nav__menu">
      <img id="logo" src="NewProject/Logo.png">
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Free Trial</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Samples</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Q-Bank</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=67fd942ed774f3de1db50cf3dd0065eb&w=1000&q=80">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <img class="img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TdpBRZ0dZhw/maxresdefault.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <p>Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=67fd942ed774f3de1db50cf3dd0065eb&w=1000&q=80">
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <p>Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image! Here are the details of the image!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="revealCard">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face">
        <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcrkTylq_NcR1xOsclrGiDsbEPFpRFlLK_UxpB4zuF9O3Uvwu5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dynamicText">
  <p class="appearOnScroll">See the magic below!</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">Signup For Your Free Beta Trial Today!</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">This text appears on scroll</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">This text appears on scroll</p>
  <p class="appearOnScroll">This text appears on scroll</p>
</div>
<div id="form">
  <form action="">
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Full Name :<span class="star"> * </span></label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Address line 1:<span class="star"> * </span></label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="address_line_1" placeholder="Address line 1" required><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Address line 2:</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="address_line_2" placeholder="Address line 2"><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Address line 3:</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="address_line_3" placeholder="Address line 3"><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="Fields">
      <label class="form__fields">Email :<span class="star"> * </span></label>
      <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail" required><br/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The content within #dynamicText is longer then the height of the div, resulting in the overflowing content to appear behind the appending div. Either of your solutions should result in a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height of the dynamicTest div which is set to 30vh. The overlapping divs is caused due to that property.